# MySQL UPDATE CASE WHEN

Tags: mysql, database

I need to update one column if another is above zero. I wrote this

```
UPDATE `product` SET `quantity`= CASE
WHEN `price` > 0
THEN `quantity` = 1000
ELSE `quantity` = 0
END
```

The problem is that this query affected only 47 rows where it should be around 1000 rows. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check how many rows it should affected:

> select count(1) from product where price>0 and quantity<>1000;
>   select count(1) from product where price<>0 and quantity<>0;

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is this:

```
UPDATE `product`
SET `quantity`= CASE WHEN `price` > 0 THEN 1000 ELSE 0 END
```

Answer (score 0):

try out this...

```
UPDATE product SET quantity = CASE WHEN price > 0 THEN 1000 ELSE 0 END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
UPDATE `product` SET `quantity`=(case when `price` > 0 then quantity='1000' else quantity='0' end)
```